# What is the sum of this series: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac 1{k(k+3)}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I was able to change $\frac 1{k(k+3)}$ into $\frac{1}{3}(k + 3) + -\frac{1}{3k}$, but am now stuck. Please help!

Comment: This is surely a duplicate question, but write out the first, say, 6 terms, and see what cancellations you can make.

Comment: You should correct your missing fraction. Write out the first six, say, terms of the series and use the algebra you just observed to see what happens.

Comment: I think it is remarkable that both comments above are the same suggestion with very close wording...

Perhaps that is an indicator that the advice is good advice :)

Comment: LOL, @Travis and I usually respond to more geometric questions. It was pretty funny.

Answer (score 2):

$HINT$

$$\frac{1}{k(k+3)}=\frac{1}{3}(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1})+(\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+2})+(\frac{1}{k+2}-\frac{1}{k+3})$$